# Java-esque enum in Swift

Tags: java, swift, enums

I have used Java for a while now and am currently learning Swift. In Java I use enumeration quite a bit when creating little games as a way of learning the language. However upon beginning to construct "races" and "weapons" in this game I came across an issue. Swift doesn't handle enum the same way Java does. So my question is how do I write the following Java code in Swift so it can be used in a similar way.

```
public enum EnumWeapon {
    WOODEN_SWORD("Wooden Sword", 4),
    STONE_SWORD("Stone Sword", 6), 
    STEEL_SWORD("Steel Sword", 8); 

    private String name;
    private int damage;

    private EnumWeapon(String name, int damage) {
        this.name = name;
        this.damage = damage;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getDamage() {
        return damage;
    }
}
```

Comment: At least post your attempt at a [tag:swift] version, StackOverflow isn't a code translation service. Also, I wouldn't expect one language idiom to be precisely duplicated in another.

Comment: Ok I'll pull together what I have. So far everything I have tried hasn't worked. I was hoping someone could point to a tutorial or something as I'm completely lost. (The code above was something I just made as an example of how I use enum's in Java, it is not what I need the enum for in Swift)

Comment: While this question is a duplicate of that question, I don't think that that question's accepted answer is all that good. It doesn't make good use of Swift's idioms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most obvious way would be:

```
public enum EnumWeapon {
    case WOODEN_SWORD
    case STONE_SWORD
    case STEEL_SWORD

    func getName() -> String {
        switch self {
        case WOODEN_SWORD:  return "Wooden Sword"
        case STONE_SWORD:   return "Stone Sword"
        case STEEL_SWORD:   return "Steel Sword"
        }
    }

    func getDamage() -> Int {
        switch self {
        case WOODEN_SWORD:  return 4
        case STONE_SWORD:   return 6
        case STEEL_SWORD:   return 8
        }
    }
}
```

If you have a single value to associate with each enum case, you can use the raw value syntax, or just use it to simplify the enum case above:

```
public enum Weapon : Int {
    case WOODEN_SWORD = 4
    case STONE_SWORD = 6
    case STEEL_SWORD = 8

    func getDamage() -> Int {
        return rawValue
    }

    func getName() -> String {
        switch self {
        case .WOODEN_SWORD: return "Wooden Sword"
        case .STONE_SWORD:  return "Stone Sword"
        case .STEEL_SWORD:  return "Steel Sword"
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, if you don't need the name, you can omit the `getName` function.  Likewise you can omit the `getDamage` function and just use `weapon.rawValue`

An even simpler way, and yet more analogous to the actual Java implementation, would be to use a struct instead of an enum, as:

```
public struct Weapon {
    public let name : String
    public let damage : Int

    private init(name:String, damage:Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.damage = damage
    }

    public static let WOODEN_SWORD = Weapon(name: "Wooden Sword", damage: 4)
    public static let STONE_SWORD = Weapon(name: "Stone Sword", damage: 6)
    public static let STEEL_SWORD = Weapon(name: "Steel Sword", damage: 8)
}
```

and, be redefining operator ==, you can get equality comparisons:

```
func == (lhs:Weapon, rhs:Weapon) -> Bool {
    return lhs.name == rhs.name && lhs.damage == rhs.damage
}
```

and, by redefining operator ~= you can get switch to work as expected:

```
func ~= (lhs:Weapon, rhs:Weapon) -> Bool {
    return lhs == rhs
}

func test(sword:Weapon) {
    switch sword {
    case Weapon.STONE_SWORD:    print("stone")
    default:                    print("something else")
    }
}

test(Weapon.STONE_SWORD)
```

A whole lot of options, mostly it just depends on what you're really trying to do and how much data you need to wrap in the enum.

Comment: Despite people marking it as a duplicate, you answered perfectly for us Java guys making the switch to Swift. A struct rather than an enum more closely resembles the Java enum in the sense of the original poster's usage.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one quick and dirty way to get it done:

```
typealias WeaponName = String
typealias WeaponDamage = Int

enum Weapon {
    case Sharp( WeaponName, WeaponDamage )
    case Blunt( WeaponName )
    case Broken

    var name: WeaponName {
        switch self {
        case let .Sharp( name, _):
            return name
        case let .Blunt( name ):
            return name
        case .Broken:
            return "Broken"
        }
    }

    var damage: WeaponDamage {
        switch self {
        case let .Sharp( _, damage ):
            return damage
        case .Broken:
            return 0
        default:
            return 5
        }
    }

}


var woodenSword = Weapon.Sharp( "Wooden Sword", 5 )
var ironSword = Weapon.Sharp( "Iron Sword", 10 )
var club = Weapon.Blunt( "Mr. Sticky" )

print( woodenSword.name )    // "Wooden Sword"
print( woodenSword.damage )  // 10
print( club.name )           // "Mr. Sticky"
```